# No UEFI password prompt installing virtualbox on 22.04

Tags: virtualbox, uefi

Installation status bar at 98% when the installation terminal window throws up:
Your system has UEFI Secure Boot enabled.
│
│ UEFI Secure Boot requires additional configuration to work with
│ third-party drivers.
│
│ The system will assist you in configuring UEFI Secure Boot. To permit
│ the use of third-party drivers, a new Machine-Owner Key (MOK) has been
│ generated. This key now needs to be enrolled in your system's firmware.
│
│ To ensure that this change is being made by you as an authorized user,
│ and not by an attacker, you must choose a password now and then confirm
│ the change after reboot using the same password, in both the "Enroll
│ MOK" and "Change Secure Boot state" menus that will be presented to you
│
│

But it never puts up a password prompt. There's no way to acknowledge  that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try with these options:

```
$ mokutil --help
...
  --help                Show help
  --list-enrolled           List the enrolled keys
  --list-new                List the keys to be enrolled
...
```

*I have not been there trying that.*